# Gradle build script failing in java 10

Tags: java, gradle

I am trying to build my program but gradle throws this error when trying to install my program
`Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not list contents of '/usr/bin/javah'. Couldn't follow symbolic link.`

Switching java versions works but is not an option because my program will be published as a package on the Arch Linux user repository. Also I am using grade 5.4.1.

Does anyone know how to get gradle to work properly on Java 9+?

Output of `gradle install --stacktrace`:

```
Task :copyRunScript FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':copyRunScript'.
> Could not list contents of '/usr/bin/javah'. Couldn't follow symbolic link.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan     to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':copyRunScript'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not list contents of '/usr/bin/javah'. Couldn't follow symbolic link.
    at org.gradle.internal.snapshot.impl.DirectorySnapshotter$1.visitFile(DirectorySnapshotter.java:99)
    at org.gradle.internal.snapshot.impl.DirectorySnapshotter$1.visitFile(DirectorySnapshotter.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.snapshot.impl.DirectorySnapshotter.snapshot(DirectorySnapshotter.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.snapshot.impl.DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.snapshot(DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.snapshot.impl.DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.snapshotAndCache(DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.java:149)
    at org.gradle.internal.snapshot.impl.DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.snapshotAndCache(DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.java:133)
    at org.gradle.internal.snapshot.impl.DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.access$200(DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.snapshot.impl.DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter$2.create(DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.java:116)
    at org.gradle.internal.snapshot.impl.DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter$2.create(DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.ProducerGuard$StripedProducerGuard.guardByKey(ProducerGuard.java:115)
    at org.gradle.internal.snapshot.impl.DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.snapshot(DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.internal.snapshot.impl.DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter$FileCollectionLeafVisitorImpl.visitCollection(DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.visitLeafCollections(AbstractFileCollection.java:233)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.visitLeafCollections(CompositeFileCollection.java:205)
    at org.gradle.internal.snapshot.impl.DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.snapshot(DefaultFileSystemSnapshotter.java:126)
    at org.gradle.internal.fingerprint.impl.AbstractFileCollectionFingerprinter.fingerprint(AbstractFileCollectionFingerprinter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.DefaultTaskFingerprinter.fingerprintTaskFiles(DefaultTaskFingerprinter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    ... 24 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Edit: This happens when Copying files through tasks

Edit: Actually if i switch jdks it just gives a different error

Comment: Can you please attach the full stacktrace by running with the `--stacktrace` flag or even better share a build scan URL by running with `--scan`?

Comment: I edited the stack trace in to the post

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I just did not have my `JAVA_HOME` set